# Conflicting versions of sha256 bit calculation

Tags: python, hash, sha, circom

I'm computing `sha256` from two different sources, both ran on bit arrays. In Python, I run

```py
from bitarray import bitarray
from hashlib import sha256

inbits = bitarray([1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0])
sha = sha256(inbits)

outbits = bitarray()
outbits.frombytes(sha.digest())
```

The other source is a [circuit implementation of sha256](https://github.com/iden3/circomlib/blob/master/circuits/sha256/sha256.circom) (implemented in circom). I'm just wondering if there are different implementations of sha256, as running the sha256 circuit and python code give different outputs.

Output from circom:

```
 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,
 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1,
 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0,
 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
```

and output from python:
`bitarray('1110111001111011010110111001100001000011011101011100000100111011001101011111000000010101110000001001100011100001100011010111011110001100100010110010111111110011111101010111111110101000101111011010010001011101000001101110101110111011011010111100101101111100')`

Comment: Sorry, meant to reply yesterday. I ran the code again and seems ok. Hex value is `ee7b5b984375c13b35f015c098e18d778c8b2ff3f57fa8bda45d06ebbb6bcb7c` and I'm running this on Python 3.10.1 (though this probably shoudn't matter, as it's the same function). I tried implementing it from [here](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf) but it gives me yet another different value. Did notice that in circom there are compressions running for 32 turns and in the document there are 64 (pg. 23 first line). Maybe a good question: shouldn't sha256 implementations be more standardized?

Comment: Had my friend run the code and she gets `40dc0873decf568a7e181687f2e0a83c93f494d246635be4045751db23b4b2da`, so it really looks like it's environment dependent.

Comment: Was probably changed in Python 3.10, as I get the same thing on a different machine running Python 3.10.0.

Comment: It turns out it was the endianess, but I don't know how to switch them in `hashlib.sha256`, so I rewrote the code in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot feed `bitarray` to hashlib and expect it to handle it. hashlib handles only full bytes so it somehow convert its input to `bytes`. Proof by code:

```
>>> from bitarray import bitarray
>>> from hashlib import sha256
>>> inbits = bitarray([0])
>>> sha256(inbits).hexdigest()
'148de9c5a7a44d19e56cd9ae1a554bf67847afb0c58f6e12fa29ac7ddfca9940'
>>> bytes(inbits)
b'p'
>>> sha256(b'p').hexdigest()
'148de9c5a7a44d19e56cd9ae1a554bf67847afb0c58f6e12fa29ac7ddfca9940'
```

We know for sure that this is not the expected result because NIST published the test vector for the single bit at 0: see 'SHA256ShortMsg.rsp' in https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Algorithm-Validation-Program/documents/shs/shabittestvectors.zip

It says the following:

```
Len = 1
Msg = 00
MD = bd4f9e98beb68c6ead3243b1b4c7fed75fa4feaab1f84795cbd8a98676a2a375
```

We can compute that using https://pypi.org/project/sha256bit/

```
>>> from sha256bit import Sha256bit
>>> Sha256bit(inbits,bitlen=len(inbits)).hexdigest()
'bd4f9e98beb68c6ead3243b1b4c7fed75fa4feaab1f84795cbd8a98676a2a375'
```

Application to your original input:

```
>>> inbits = bitarray([1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0])
>>> Sha256bit(inbits,bitlen=len(inbits)).hexdigest()
'39e78e40303b445bd9298f30ccb55e810585edce97bf287f970ca8d891fb7996'
>>> outbits = bitarray()
>>> outbits.frombytes(sha256bit(inbits,bitlen=len(inbits)).digest())
>>> outbits
bitarray('0011100111100111100011100100000000110000001110110100010001011011110110010010100110001111001100001100110010110101010111101000000100000101100001011110110111001110100101111011111100101000011111111001011100001100101010001101100010010001111110110111100110010110')
```